# How to check session expired when user is idle codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

i would like to check if the user is `idle for more than 5 minutes`, they will `be redirected to login page`. i have no idea the best practices to do this. gimme solution. i code with codeigniter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

This can be done with combination of jQuery/javascript/Ajax and a Codeigniter function.

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var currentSessionValue = 1;
    // pseudo code
    setTimeout(checkSession, 5000);
    function checkSession() {
         $.ajax({
            url: "CheckSession/check_session", //Change this URL as per your settings
            success: function(newVal) {
                if (newVal != currentSessionValue);
                    currentSessionValue = newVal;
                    alert('Session expired.');
                    window.location = 'Your redirect login URL goes here.';
                }
         });
    }
</script>
```

---

**Codeigniter**

```
class CheckSession extends Controller{
    public function __construct(){
        session_start();
    }
    public function check_session(){
       //Below last_visited should be updated everytime a page is accessed.
       $lastVisitTime = $this->session->userdata("last_visited");
       $fiveMinutesBefore = date("YmdHi", "-5 minutes");

       echo date("YmdHi", strtotime($lastVisitTime)) > $fiveMinutesBefore > 1 : 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: where does $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in'); come from? u havent set it.

Comment: I edited to give more details on is_logged_in index.

Comment: i combine your answer with second answer, it works! thank you.

Comment: glad it helped.

Comment: @Rahi, I just want to know if last visited time should be updated every time then how can we get the first login time?

Comment: @user9437856 it depends on where you want to use first login time. Depending on your answer it can be achieved either on JS or PHP side.

Answer (score 2):

Simply store the `last_visited` timestamp as a session variable. Next time when the user visits, check for difference in current timestamp against the one in session. If it is more than 5 minutes, sign out user.

```
$this->load->library('session');
$this->session->set_userdata(array(
                            'last_visited' => time()
                    ));
```

Comment: on every function i must check it?

Comment: You might be writing like this `class xxxx extends MY_Controller { }` .. So in the MY_Controller.php, specify this login in __construct in `MY_Controller`. It will get called automatically for all actions.

Comment: thank you, i combine your answer with above answer and it works!

Answer (score 0):

I check session expiry by simply try to read a variable I stored on login

I placed this in `My_Controller` in the folder `application/core`, and extend all my other controller based on this.

in the class, I have this function

```
 function _is_logged_in()
    {
       return !empty($this->session->userdata('user_id'));
    }
```

in my class, in the  `__construct` i do this

```
if (!$this->_is_logged_in()) {
     $this->_log_out("Session Expired", base_url("login"));
}
```

so when i make a request, if the session has expired, it redirects to login, no need to check every 5 minutes.